# Pandas, count number of changes that occur in date column based on info from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column that counts the number of times the date changed based on a unique identifier from another column.

Example:

```
Date -     ID Code -   Number of Changes
01.03.21   B017               0
02.03.21   B017               1
01.03.21   A018               0
03.03.21   A019               0
04.03.21   A019               1
06.03.21   A019               2
07.03.21   A021               0
```

So if the date has changed one time for the ID Code B017 then it'll record 1, and if it has changed twice it will record 2 etc. and do the same for every individual ID in the ID Code column.

While I know how to create a count of the number of changes in the date column overall, I haven't figured out a simple way to do these counts based on the ID Code.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates of the same data for the same id, then you can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together with [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as follows:

```
df['Number of Changes'] = df.groupby('ID Code').cumcount()
```

Result:

```
        Date    ID Code Number of Changes
0   01.03.21       B017                 0
1   02.03.21       B017                 1
2   01.03.21       A018                 0
3   03.03.21       A019                 0
4   04.03.21       A019                 1
5   06.03.21       A019                 2
6   07.03.21       A021                 0
```